# PostgreSQL in Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, amazon-ec2

I try to set up Amazon EC2 with Vagrant and Chef-zero. Chef contains only one receipt for the installation of Nginx, Ruby, PostgreSQL, that is those utilities that are necessary for a Ruby on Rails stack. For PostgreSQL installation I use this cookbook https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/postgresql. It automatically adds “local all all peer” to the end of pg_hba.conf. If I run Chef on my local machine in VirtualBox, everything is OK. But if I run it on Amazon, PostgreSQL gives an error  “invalid authentication method "peer”. What is the reason? Maybe, I should use Amazon RDS instead of running the Ruby stack and PostgreSQL on the same machine? Locally, I use Centos 7.2, but on Amazon EC2 - Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09.0.

**/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/pg_hba.conf**

```
# This file was automatically generated and dropped off by Chef!

# PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File
# ===================================================
#
# Refer to the "Client Authentication" section in the PostgreSQL
# documentation for a complete description of this file.

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

###########
# Other authentication configurations taken from chef node defaults:
###########

local   all             postgres                                ident

local   all             all                                     ident

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5

host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
```

**logfile:**

```
LOG:  invalid authentication method "peer"
CONTEXT:  line 24 of configuration file "/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/pg_hba.conf"
FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
```

Comment: What version of postgresql?

Comment: Are you positive that you're running PostgreSQL 9.2?  "peer" was added in 9.x and if you really have an 8.x server it won't work.  Using RDS would also be an option though it can be a bit pricy.

Comment: Unless required, you should definitely use RDS PostgreSQL instead of  managing own postgresql server. Also, avoiding putting database stack and ruby stack would be better even if managing own server is required.